# Containerd GELF logging driver does not send logs to graylog

Tags: kubernetes, graylog, containerd

Can anyone give me some hints how can i send **logs from containerd 1.6.19 to graylog using the GELF logging driver** ?

I have set  in my **/etc/containerd/config.toml** :

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
LogDriver = "gelf"
LogOpt = ["gelf-address=udp://1.2.3.4:12022"]
SystemdCgroup = true
Environment = ["ENVIRON=testing"]
```

(redacted values)

I can see the configuration is applied as per **/var/log/messages** :

```
Root: Options:map[Environment:[ENVIRON=testing] LogDriver:gelf LogOpt:[gelf-address=udp://1234:12022]
```

However i cannot see any traffic from the containerd server to the specified IP and/or port.

I can see  i can connect to the graylog server/port :

```
ncat -u -zvw 2 1234 12022
```

Ncat: Connected to 1234:12022.

I have started multiple containers on the containerd server in multiple ways, manually created logs to make sure there's data to be sent, but i cannot detect nothing being sent to my graylog server...

```
sudo tcpdump -i any -n -X udp port 12022
```

(for example)

Any clues are greatly appreciated.

PS:

I was upgrading a kubernetes cluster which was using docker engine, where sending logs to graylog in a similar way worked fine.
I am simply trying to rework it for containerd engine.